# ionic 4 firebase how to check if email already exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase phone authentication in my ionic app. After login, I am asking the user their email.

If user types email that already exists firebase shows the following message.

```
M {code: "auth/email-already-in-use", message: "The email address is already in use by another account."}
code: "auth/email-already-in-use"
message: "The email address is already in use by another account."
```

But I can't get how to check these error codes in my ionic app.

I am also sending verification mail to verify email

here is the code

I have check checking error codes with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, but as I have phone authentication how can I check error codes?
Thank you in advance

here is the code 
.html

```
<form [formGroup] = "userDetails">

 <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="floating">Enter your name</ion-label>
            <ion-input formControlName = "name" type = "text"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

<ion-label position="floating">Enter your email </ion-label>
          <ion-input formControlName = "Email" type = "text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

          <ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!userDetails.valid" (click)="submit(Email.value, name.value )">Submit</ion-button>

</form>
```

.ts

```
     userDetails = this.fb.group({
            name : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*') ] ],
            Email : ['', [ Validators.required , Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')  ]],
          })

    submit(email, name ){

    console.log(email)
    console.log(name)


    var mail = email
    let nm = name

this.afauth.authState.subscribe(user =>  {
      if(user) {

    let number = user.phoneNumber

user.updateProfile({
          displayName : nm
        })

          user.updateEmail(mail).then(function(){
              console.log("Email updated")

                user.sendEmailVerification().then(function(){
                  console.log("mail sent")
                }).catch(function(error) {
                  console.log(error)
                })

          }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
          })         
})      }
```

Comment: Are u using both phone authentication and email authentication

Comment: yes. Sending mail to verify email

Comment: @PeterHaddad to see if he can help further...

Comment: @pratikjaiswal if you are getting the error in the log why dont you use it in a dialog? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/dialogs

Comment: I have email as formcontol. When users enters already existed email firebase shows error code -auth/email-already-in-use. My simple problem is how to get this error code in an angular ionic app..

Comment: The thing is I can get error codes in the promise or observables using .catch or catcherror. But, here I am getting an error on the form control. If user types existing email, firebase giving error. How to catch such an error?

Comment: can you add your code regarding this "getting an error on form control" also please tag my name

Comment: you are getting the error on button click `submit(Email.value, name.value )` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210385/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-pratik-jaiswal).